# Using Nested OR/AND In Designer 2010 Workflow Conditions

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, conditional

A series of actions in an SPD 2010 workflow I'm working in needs to run when quite a few conditions, arranged in an "If this AND that are true, OR if something AND another thing are true, OR (etc)" fashion are true.

Just arranging the conditions in an alternating If-And-Or-And-Or-And-etc arrangement doesn't seem to be working, and the actions shouldn't run repeatedly so I can't just make multiple sets of conditions. What am I missing, and how can I get this working?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a stop workflow at the end of each set of actions so it won't further evaluate.

For example:

> If A and B then Action 1 then Stop workflow
>   If B or C then Action 1 then Stop workflow
>   If A and C then Action 1 then Stop workflow

If it successfully enters any of the condition blocks, it executes Action 1 then stops further evaluating.

Alternate solution:
Have a hidden field in your list that is a checkbox. Then, instead of executing whatever your action is, set your checkbox to true.  Then it doesn't matter if you enter multiple cases, the only action taken at that level is to set your checkbox.  Then, after you evaluate all your conditions, add a step where you take action 1 if your checkbox is true.

For example:

> Step 1
>   -If A and B then set TakeAction to true
>   -If B or C then set TakeAction to true
>   -If A and C then set TakeAction to true
>   Step 2
>   -If TakeAction=true then Action 1
>   Step 3 ... (continue with the rest of your workflow)

Comment: This would solve the problem, if not for the way my workflow is structured. These conditions and their resultant action is only preparation for the main body of the workflow.
Thanks for the help anyhow!

Comment: Edited to add another option for you.